# How to assign value of <s:radio> to another variable using <s:set> in struts2

Tags: session, struts2, struts-tags

I'm trying to assign the value of radio button `ans1` to another variable `ans_submit`.

```xml
<s:form action="ques2" namespace="/questions" theme="simple">

    Question 1: <s:property value="#session.ques1.question"/><br/><br/>

<s:radio list="#session.ques1.option1" name="ans1" value="%{'option1'}" label="1. "/><br/>
<s:radio list="#session.ques1.option2" name="ans1" value="%{'option2'}" label="2. "/><br/>
<s:radio list="#session.ques1.option3" name="ans1" value="%{'option3'}" label="3. "/><br/>
<s:radio list="#session.ques1.option4" name="ans1" value="%{'option4'}" label="4. "/><br/>

    <s:submit name="submit" value=" Next"/>

</s:form>

<s:set var="ans_submit" value="%{#ans1}" scope="session" />
```

But when I retrieve `ans_submit` in action class, it is giving `null`.
I have to keep `<s:set>` tag outside of `<s:form>` tag. Because there is no variable defined as such in my model.
I don't want to use JavaScript!

Comment: Why do you need to set this variable?

Comment: There are set of `questions` like ques1, ques2, ques3 and so on..as given above.  
So I need to keep the `answers` in session, so as to evaluate and calculate the marks(how many of them are `right`) at the end based on these `answers`.

Comment: I know that I can set these answer values using `getModel()` of `ModelDriven` interface, but I want to set these values on jsp itself.
I can also use jstl tags **<c:set var="ans_submit" value="${param.ans1}" scope="session"/>**. But it can be set only after submit button is pressed and that too on the next jsp page. `I want to set the value of this variable as soon as one changes the option immediately`.

Comment: What do you mean by immediately? Do you submit the value as soon as one changes the option?

Comment: I want to give back button functionality.
So when the back button is pressed, the question moves to previous page and when one wants to change the previous answer, he can do this only by changing the option. And This `change of option` should reflect in my session variable.

Answer (score 0):

Use a map to populate a radio tag.

```xml
<s:radio name="ans1" list="#{'option1': '1. ','option2': '2. ','option3': '3. ','option4': '4. '}" />
```

In the action class you should have a property for `ans1` where the value would be set when you submit the form. This property is local to the action instance which is created every time when you make a new request. So, you need to save the value in the session.

```
session.put("ans1", ans1);
```

Now to retrieve this value from session in another action you can initialize the `ans1` property

```
ans1 = (String) session.get("ans1");
```

or you can preset the value in the radio tag using a `value` attribute.

```xml
<s:radio name="ans1" list="#{'option1': '1. ','option2': '2. ','option3': '3. ','option4': '4. '}" value="%{#session.ans1}"/>
```