# Radio button selection is not being saved on the front end in Struts2 upgrade to Struts 6.3.0.2

Tags: struts2, weblogic12c, ognl

I have some radio button where I can select one radio button at a time and safe it. It is being saved in the database but on the frontend it is not being saved. There are no error. It is able to gather from the database when I checked on the console but it is not displaying on the frontend. There is no error on the console and neither is there any error on the developer tools on MS Edge
Please assist.

```java
public class getDotsCarRentalAction extends GenericMappingDispatchAction{

    public String saveCr(){
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        String result = null;
        DotsCarRentalForm frm = null;
        DotsCarRental dotsCarRental = new DotsCarRental();
        dotsCarRental = (DotsCarRental) session.getAttribute(DBConstants.sessionCarId);
        frm = (DotsCarRentalForm) form;
        dotsCarRental = frm.getFormData(dotsCarRental);
        result = frm.getFctSelected().trim();

        if(result == null || result.length() < 1) result = "CARRENTAL";
        ActionErrors errors = frm.validate(getTextProvider(),request);
        if(errors != null){
            saveErrors(errors);
            return "CARRENTAL";
        }
        session.setAttribute(DBConstants.sessionCarId,dotsCarRental);
        return result;
    }

    

    public String getCr(){
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        DotsCarRental dotsCarRental = new DotsCarRental;
        dotsCarRental = (DotsCarRental) session.getAttribute(DBConstants.sessionCarId);
        DotsCarRentalForm frm = new DotsCarRentalForm();
        if(dotsCarRental !=null){
            frm.setFormData(dotsCarRental);
        }
        frm.setFctSelected(null);
        frm.setValSelected(null);
        

    request.setAttribute("dotsCarRentalForm",frm);


        return "success";

    }


}
```

```html
<div class="form-group" style="width:100%; clear: both;">
    <div>Staff</div><br />
    <s:iterator var="srr" value="#rr">
    <span>
    <s:radio name="rentalReason" style="font-weight: normal; padding: 2px; word-wrap: break-word;"      value="#frm.rentalReason" list="#srr" listKey="lookupTitle" listValue="lookupTitle" /><br/>
    </span>
    </s:iterator>
    </div>

    <div>
    <a class="btn btn-outline-primary"   href="javascript:document.forms[0].fctSelected.value='SAVEEOTAF';document.forms[0].submit();">SAVE AS   DRAFT</a>
    
    </div>

    <!--struts-dots.xml-->
    <action name="SaveDotsCarRental" class="com.dots.action.getDotsCarRentalAction" method="saveCr">

    <!--struts-generated.xml-->
    <action name="SaveDotsCarRental" class="com.dots.action.getDotsCarRentalAction" method="saveCr">

    <!--viewDotsCarRental.jsp-->
    <form name="form" method="post" action="SaveDotsCarRental.do" onsubmit="return false">
```

Comment: It is not clear what are you trying to save and where it is saved. The value should be retrieved back from the database and populate the action. If it's not populating then provide more details where you prepare the value and how it accessed from the page.

Comment: Hi I managed to resolve the issue. In the jsp file I need to use %{value of radio selection} to see the radio selection on the front-end

Comment: This is called an OGNL engine to evaluate an expression. Find more about it in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Some attributes of the Struts tags require to forse OGNL to evaluate a value. Especially the [`<s:radio>`](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/radio-tag.html) tag when `#` is referenced. According to the doc none of the attributes are evaluated. So if you want to use OGNL expression in the tag attribute you have to forse OGNL.

How to preset the value of the `<s:radio>` tag

```xml
<s:radio name="rentalReason" style="font-weight: normal; padding: 2px; word-wrap: break-word;"      value="%{#frm.rentalReason}" list="%{#srr}" listKey="lookupTitle" listValue="lookupTitle" /><br/>
```

You can read more about [How to assign value of <s:radio> to another variable using <s:set> in struts2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23854112/573032).